# How to determine the texture used in the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css

In the below components, I want to determine what effects used in order to replicate the design. The fonts, border, texture, light-like (offline/online) text.

Objective:
to replicate the design using Photoshop or CSS

## Navigation

[image]

## Panel

[image]

## Tab-nagivation

[image]

Comment: As-is, your question is very broad for this site's format. There are most likely a lot of effects combined. A good answer to your question would be multiple paragraphs long and would be an in-depth tutorial. That is beyond the scope of this site. Please [edit] your question to include you attempts, so we can, short and concise, give you guidance to solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IN this design there is not only one effect, it is a mix of many effects.
Sometimes designers uses photoshop layer effects like emboss, drop shadows, border etc. 
Here they are used on the texts . Gradient effect, emboss effect and drop shadow effect.
But not limited to them ..
In photoshop or any software with same purpose, the result you wanna see can be achieved in endless ways. So it is up to you.
Just design the layout : sections and give it a 3d effect the way you want. 
It is up to your imagination...

Seems like there is an overall color control that turns design to brown too.